# how do I force-hide the soft keyboard

Tags: android

*Since this topic is quite popular, I have to say that I searched tons of similar questions and still don't have a working solution.*

Problem short description: in my `Activity` I have a "search mode", when it starts I show the soft keyboard, when it finishes, I want to hide the keyboard, but can't find a way to do it.

What I have tried:

- using flag `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` instead of 0
- using flag `InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS` instead of 0
- setting `windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`
- setting `windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Nothing seems to work, the keyboard stays visible. The code starting the "search mode":

```
     private void onStartSearch(){
    isSearch = true;
    tvMyFriends.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    etSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    etSearch.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.on_show_search));
    etSearch.requestFocus();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    imm.showSoftInput(etSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

The code that finishes the "search mode":

```
     private void onCancelSearch(){
    Animation animHideSearch = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.on_cancel_search);
    animHideSearch.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            /* no action required */
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            etSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvMyFriends.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isSearch = false;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            if(etSearch.getText().toString().length()>0)
                etSearch.setText("");
            etSearch.clearFocus();
            imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(etSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
             /* no action required */
        }
    });
    etSearch.startAnimation(animHideSearch);
}
```

**The question:** how can I force the damn keyboard to disappear?

**UPD:** set a bounty. Still looking for a *reliable, device-independent solution* to force-hide the soft keyboard OR to detect whether the keyboard is currently showing.

Comment: Wait a second, `imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(etSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);` doesn't work? This one worked for me.

Comment: nope, the keyboard remains visible

Comment: Are you sure that that animation listener event method runs properly?

Comment: @Zhuinden yep, I can see it. The `onAnimationEnd()` callback is definitely invoked

Comment: I used `inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);` and you said that didn't work, so I can't seem to help :(

Comment: well, `toggleSoftInput()` works, but I'd need a safe way to determine IF the keyboard is currently visible, and there's no such way AFAIK

Comment: Maybe hideSoftInputFromInputMethod before changing the Visibility of the EditText to GONE

Comment: @Francescoverheye just changed the sequence to                 `imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(etSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);`
                `etSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);`  and also tried 2 other flags, the keyboard still remains visible

Comment: oh well.. but post this as answer since you got me thinking the right way. `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);` works if called BEFORE hiding the `EditText`. Just that simple

Comment: Looks like I can't get your bounty but I'm happy that it helped you. It was the first thing i thought but wasn't sure about it.

Comment: why can't you? I wasn't thinking about how `getWindowToken()` works until seeing your comment, so you deserve it. Just make it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the keyboard before changing the Visibility of you EditText to GONE.

```
...
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
etSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
...
```

Comment: well I can award in 23 hours, which I'm going to do tomorrow. Thanks. And better change the method to `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);`, just for folks having the same issue